# Prevent DocuSign Text tab from entering same text in other Text tabs

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I added a list of 3 separate Text tabs to a document (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber), but when the person is signing if they fill out the FirstName field the rest of the text fields fill out with the same information. What property do I need to set to make each text field unique and prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If two fields have the same Label, data will populate between them.

You need to change those fields so they have different Labels to prevent this from occurring.